# How to display values only for the past 3 months in a table

Tags: powerbi, dax

I've got a table in Power BI that shows Treatment Count by Month/Year

Basically, I created a "Treatment Count" measure that is the following.

```
Treatment Count = 
(COUNTROWS(FILTER('MyTable',
('MyTable'[Successful Run?] = "Y" || 'MyTable'[Successful Run?] = "N") &&
CONTAINSSTRING('MyTable'[Type], "rinse") = FALSE)))
```

Currently, my table shows all months/year that are within the date range select on my slicer, but what I want to do, is always show the treatment count only for the past 3 months based on the maximum date selected on my slicer.

How would I be able to do this? do I have to change my measure, or is this a setting within the table I created?

Comment: Can you share a sample .pbix or sample data?

Comment: You may want to look for a (second,) disconnected date table to choose from and to filter against your dates.

Comment: but what I want to do, is always show the treatment count only for the past 3 months based on the maximum date selected on my slicer.

You'd have to modify the filter on your table... something like this: (adding a filter).

FILTER( 'MyTable', MyTable[Date]>=DATEADD(month,MyTable[Date],3)
&& <other filters> )